# Cannot delete comment added during review

Tags: bug

While working through the Close Vote queue, I ran into a bug with comment handling.

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284261/how-to-show-a-range-of-rows-only-when-i-select-a-specific-value-from-a-dropdown), I began to enter a comment to guide the OP, but messed it up. I attempted to edit the comment, and got an error.

Copied the text of my edit, and added it as a new comment.

Attempted to delete original messed up comment. Appeared to work, but comment still showed. Tried again, same. Wanted to try again, but at this point the delete `X` icon no longer showed up. Right-clicked on question title, opened in another tab. Located messed up comment there, and deleted it successfully.

I've tried to reproduce this on a couple more questions, but no go.

It happened. I'm not crazy. My mother had me tested.

Comment: "It happened. I'm not crazy. My mother had me tested." Incredible.

Comment: Did you break StackOverflow? :P

Comment: @JaredBurrows - it was only broken for a small period of time, in an isolated part of space. I suspect that there was some transient event that caused the failure of my first edit, and the client-side scripts didn't recover properly to support a retry. (A new window started fresh, so no problem there.)

Comment: So what happens to this question now? Are you going to delete or ask for confirmation on the issue? (I am trying to get more in "meta").

Comment: @JaredBurrows - I'm going to wait, and hope that an SO programmer is able to either pull logs to determine what went wrong, or do a code inspection on the relevant client-side code. It's always nicest when someone can reproduce a problem, but sometimes we don't have that luxury.

Comment: Ok, I want to read what they have to say.

Comment: The incomplete Comment has now been deleted?  I do not see it.  Note that while the window of time to Edit is limited (in part by the commenting acts of others), the ability to delete ones own comments depends only on being logged in.

Comment: @hardmath - Yes, it was deleted, in a second session. Was within a minute or so of creation, so hadn't hit the 5 minute edit limit yet.